# Buffer? Can't print a "real time" string

Tags: image, buffer, processing

I'm trying to make a text changing gradually color.

What I'm done now is something like this:

```
void printDaString(){
  for(int i = 128; i < 255; i ++){
    fontFill(color(i));
    print("This is da string!", x, y);
    delay(10);
  }
}
```

- `void fontFill(color toSet)` change an image color with `toSet` and do `color fontColFill = toSet`
- `void print(String toPrint, float x, float y)` performs a cycle where every letter of the string is printed with a piece of image [In other words, my font is a MsPaint-drawed font =P and `print` replaces `text`].
- As you know, `color color(int value)` return a gray scaled color if `value` is between `0` and `255`.

I tried with `delay(10)` hoping that it would be sufficient to make a flush [of a buffer, or something like that], but nothing!

What the program does now is just render the last screen, so what I see is only a white string printed D=

Any tip?

P.S. I chose using an image as font due to smooth-issues.
P.P.S. Parsing `int i` as argument would be a solution, but would be a huge cost!

Comment: @paddy: I tagged this thread with `processing`, the language I'm using...

Comment: My mistake, just looked like a lame tag choice, especially alongside tags like `image` and `buffer`.  I didn't know such a language existed.

Comment: sorry, your code is not clear. What are you trying to do here? (x and y aren't defined, for instance, so it's impossible to tell what you want your code to achieve). Can you describe, in plain text, what you want the program to do and what problem you're actually running into?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that's because the draw() only renders the image at the end of each loop. So your for loop executes entirely, setting the color to 255, before execution returns to draw to go on and render the image, already white. You need to do it with an if and it will work. I set an example using a global var but you can adapt it to your needs. Also delay is to be avoided, for the same reason, it only hangs the program. You may like to have a look in [this article](http://wiki.processing.org/w/I_display_images_in_sequence_but_I_see_only_the_last_one._Why%3F) form wiki

```
int i = 128;

void draw() {
  printDaString();
}

void printDaString() {      
  if (i < 255) {
    fontFill(color(i));
    print(i);
    i++;
  }
}

void fontFill(color c) {
  fill(c);
  ellipse(width/2, height/2, 30, 30);
}
```

or even simpler:

```
int i = 128;

void draw() {
  i = i<255? i+=1:128;
  fontFill(i);
}

void fontFill(int c) {
  fill(c);
  noStroke();
  ellipse(width/2, height/2, 30, 30);
}
```

Comment: What I have to do is a bit more complex, but I understood.
Finally I made a class, so I can manage everithing.
Probably I will put the whole thing in a Thread at the end!

Comment: Good it helped. I thought it was more complicated, but as there was not all the code I made this simple so you could get it.

Comment: Actually is a bit more complicated, because I would be able to print something BEFORE  `draw()` ends...
This is because I want to refresh only a small area of the screen, not everything in the frame.